# Integer value doesn't compare equal to a float in Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to compare two values

```
y = 1
ye = 1.0000
```

If I compare in Matlab for example `y == ye` I get `0`?!

The data in `y` is read from a text file...could that have something to do with this?

Comment: you compare elements, not vectors, so your question in not about vectors, it's about comparing integers to floats, don't you think?

Comment: Oh yes, thank you and sorry about that =)

Comment: What does `ye(1)-y(1)` give you? Maybe the values in the vector `ye` are not exactly 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try printing in full precision on both vectors:

```
fprintf('%.15f\n',x(:))
```

Instead, when you compare floating points, use something like:

```
abs(x1-x2) < e
```

Where `e` is some appropriate small value

Comment: That's it! I got it. Thank you very much. Silly me x)